# $\frac{0}{0}$ means functions have a common factor and can be simplified?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, limits, rational-functions

Say for example we have the following function

$$\frac{2x+8}{x^2+x-12}$$
at $-4$ both functions have the same value which is zero which means at this point the functions cross.

> How is it that their division at this given point means they must share a common factor and thus can be simpilfied?

Comment: hint: factor theorem

Comment: so when f(x) = zero it simply means that the function has roots and can be further simplified, right?

Comment: I still want to ask, what does it mean when I divide a function over another function? if I wanted to divide a simple number say 10 over 2 it's like saying I want to to distribute 10 equally into two units but when I say f(x)/g(x) what does it mean ? and how is it different to divide two functions that cross at a given point vs two that dont?

Comment: Yes, they share a common factor since they both have roots at $x=-4$, namely $x+4$: $2x+8=2(x+4)$ and $x^2+x-12=(x+4)(x-3)$

Comment: It's the fact that a polynomial can be factored into first degree polynomial (with possibly complex coefficients) or second degree polynomials (if you only allow for real coefficients). For the polynomial to have a root somewhere, then some of it's factors also have to have it.

Answer (score 4):

Not all such functions can be simplified. Take for example $f(x)=x$ and $g(x)=e^x-1$. Then while both functions have a root at $0$, their ratio
$$\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}=\frac{x}{e^x-1}$$
cannot be simplified (without say appealing to a Taylor expansion).

The point is that there is something special about the ratio of polynomials with matching roots. This comes from the [factor theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factor_theorem) which states that if $h(x)$ is a polynomial, it has a factor of $(x-a)$ if and only if $h(a)=0$.

So, if $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ *are polynomials* and they both have a root at $a$, that is $f(a)=g(a)=0$, then we can write $f(x)=(x-a)p(x)$ and $g(x)=(x-a)q(x)$ where $\deg(p(x))<\deg(f(x))$ and $\deg(q(x))<\deg(g(x))$.

Hence we have

$$\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}=\frac{(x-a)p(x)}{(x-a)q(x)}$$

and in particular for $x\ne a$, we can simplify this to

$$\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}=\frac{p(x)}{q(x)}$$

Note that at $x=a$, the ratio $\dfrac{f(x)}{g(x)}$ is undefined.

Comment: thanks, I was under the false impression that 0/0 implies more that just " if h(x) is a polynomial, it has a factor of (x−a) if and only if h(a)=0." and that i t can be simplified

Answer (score 1):

The fact that they have a factor $x-a$ where $a$ is a root to the polynomial $p(x)$ follows that if you try to divide it by $x-a$ you'll get $p(x) = q(x)(x-a)+r(x)$ where $r(x)$ is a polynomial of degree less than one (that is a constant $C$), $q(x)$ being a polynomial. Now $0 = p(a) = q(a)(a-a)+r(a)=r(a)=C$, cosequently $C=0$ so $p(x) = q(x)(x-a)$, that is that $(x-a)$ is indeed a factor of $p(x)$.

Comment: thanks I understand now, I hope this doesn't sound stupid but why is when f(a) = 0 then x-a is considered a factor while f(a)= any constant but 0 then x-a is not a factor? what does it mean that a function crosses the x-axis?

Comment: @Raed It's because given $x-a$ as a candidate factor then $f(x) = q(x)(x-a)+R$ for a constant $R$, insert $x=a$ and you see that $f(a)=R$. That is $(x-a)$ is a factor (ie $f(x)$ can be expressed as $f(x)=q(x)(x-a)$ for some polynomial $q(x)$) if and only if $f(a) = 0$.